# Article.download() error 404 url not found

Tags: python, tkinter

so basically i made this program in py file it work perfectly fine but until I made it into a exe file it doesn't work again I had import all the library so that it can detect the library but now the URL is not found is it because there is no internet connection if not how to connect it ?

[image]

this is my code

```
import tkinter as tk
import nltk
from textblob import TextBlob
from newspaper import Article
def summarize():

    nltk.download('punkt')

    url = utext.get('1.0','end').strip()
    article = Article(url)

    article.download()
    article.parse()

    article.nlp()

    title.config(state='normal')
    author.config(state='normal')
    publish.config(state='normal')
    summary.config(state='normal')
    sentiment.config(state='normal')

    title.delete('1.0', 'end')
    title.insert('1.0', article.title)

    author.delete('1.0', 'end')
    author.insert('1.0', article.authors)

    publish.delete('1.0', 'end')
    publish.insert('1.0', article.publish_date)

    summary.delete('1.0', 'end')
    summary.insert('1.0', article.summary)

    analysis = TextBlob(article.text)
    sentiment.delete('1.0', 'end')
    sentiment.insert('1.0', f'Polarity: {analysis.polarity} Sentiment: {"positive" if analysis.polarity > 0 else "negative" if analysis.polarity < 0 else "neutral"}')


    title.config(state='disabled')
    author.config(state='disabled')
    publish.config(state='disabled')
    summary.config(state='disabled')
    sentiment.config(state='disabled')

    # print(f'Title: {article.title}')
    # print(f'Authors: {article.authors}')
    # print(f'Publication Date: {article.publish_date}')
    # print(f'Summary: {article.summary}')


    analysis = TextBlob(article.text)
    print(analysis.polarity)
    print(f'Sentiment {"positive" if analysis.polarity > 0 else "negative" if analysis.polarity < 0 else "neutral"}')
#
#Graphical User Interface
root = tk.Tk()
root.title('News Summarizer')
root.geometry('1200x600')

#title
tLabel = tk.Label(root, text='Title')
tLabel.pack()

title = tk.Text(root, height=1, width=140)
title.config(state='disabled',bg='#dddddd')
title.pack()

#author
aLabel = tk.Label(root, text='Author')
aLabel.pack()

author = tk.Text(root, height=1, width=140)
author.config(state='disabled',bg='#dddddd')
author.pack()

#publish date
pLabel = tk.Label(root, text='Publish Date')
pLabel.pack()

publish = tk.Text(root, height=1, width=140)
publish.config(state='disabled',bg='#dddddd')
publish.pack()

#summary
sLabel = tk.Label(root, text='Summary')
sLabel.pack()

summary = tk.Text(root, height=20, width=140)
summary.config(state='disabled',bg='#dddddd')
summary.pack()

#Sentiment Analysis
saLabel = tk.Label(root, text='Sentiment Analysis')
saLabel.pack()

sentiment = tk.Text(root, height=1, width=140)
sentiment.config(state='disabled',bg='#dddddd')
sentiment.pack()

#url
uLabel = tk.Label(root, text='URL')
uLabel.pack()

utext = tk.Text(root, height=1, width=140)
utext.pack()

#button
btn = tk.Button(root, text='Summarize', command= summarize)
btn.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

this is my error can anyone help me what is wrong in here ?

Comment: If you look at the URL in the error message, looks like a bunch of separate URLs are getting concatenated together. This looks to be due to a white space issue (note the whitespace HTML character in there) but hard to day - maybe you can post more of the actual code doing the processing?

Comment: wait ill show u my code

Comment: ok i edited the post

Comment: don't post error messages as pictures